# C++ DLL referencing functions and classes from C++.exe

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

Using Visual Studio 17

I have a C++.exe written and another Project for a dll written in the same solution. 
I am intending to use the DLL project to link to my C++.exe application, with the DLL being able to reference the classes and functions in my C++.exe project.

I am having some trouble as when i build my solution the DLL project asks for linkage to the C++.obj objects created. Is there any way i can use the functions in the C++ executable without complicating the codes?

Best
Ben

Comment: Typically, .dlls export functions that .exe's can use.  Not vice versa...  Q: Any chance you can break out the "shared functions" and put them in a .dll that *both* .exe's can use?

Comment: Yes i understand thats the typical way, but im trying to use the dll project as a wrapper library for my c++.exe so i can export them to excel.
what do you mean by shared functions?

Comment: You can always re-write everything from [COM/ActiveX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/com-clients-and-servers) ;)  The kind of .exe you're looking for used to be called an "Out of Process Component".  You can share compile-time code by sharing source files; you can share runtime code by sharing .dlls, and you can refactor your existing code into a .dll to make it runtime sharable.  Those are your choices :)

Comment: Q: What exactly are you trying to "import into Excel"????

Comment: my c++.exe has classes and functions inside(it is initially written in .exe mode), the DLL project intends to wrap them so i can export these functions to Excel. Do i have to rewrite everything or is there some add ons i can do?

Comment: COM/ActiveX was a technology developed Microsoft developed in the late 90's to handle this kind of thing.  .Net has since replaced COM/ActiveX ... but the level of "sharing" is the assembly.  Not an .exe.  Sorry - but it sounds like you need to compile your old code into a new .dll.  You *cannot* use your .exe as-is.

Comment: @paulsm4: If his executable exports some functions, then yes he may be able to use the executable as-is. There are a few possible difficulties (mostly using the std lib in a DLL), but they may not arise in his case, and are usually easy to deal with if they do arise.

Comment: If your DLL uses exports from an executable, then only this executable will be able to use the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require complicating your code (beyond the usual for exporting functions from a DLL in general, anyway).

I suspect your current problem is mostly with the build environment, but let's give a quick example of working (tested) code for the sort of thing you're trying to do.

Here's the code for a super-simple executable with an exported function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllexport) foo() {
        printf("in foo\n"); 
    }
}

int main() {
    getch();
}
```

Note that this needs a `main` to serve as its entry point, even though it won't (at least normally) be invoked. Of course, it could have `WinMain` as its entry point instead--either way, it won't actually be used. We just need something to satisfy the linker so it'll produce the executable.

...and here's a header the declare its exported function so something else (our DLL) can use it:

```
#pragma once

extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllimport) foo();
}
```

We can build the executable fairly normally, except we have to ensure that it uses the standard library in a DLL (otherwise its standard library won't be initialized correctly, so it won't work): `cl /MD trash9.cpp`

Then we have the code for the DLL

```
#include "trash9.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllexport) bar() {
        printf("in bar\n");
        foo();
        printf("back in bar\n");
    }
}

void DllMain() {}
```

...and here's its header:

```
#pragma once

extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllimport) bar();
}
```

The DLL also needs to use the standard library in a DLL, so we build it something like this: `cl /MD /LD trash8.cpp trash9.lib`. The `/MD` means it should use the standard library in a DLL, and the `/LD` means this should create an executable (instead of an executable, as it would be default).

Finally, here's an executable that uses `bar`:

```
#include "trash8.h"

int main() { 
    bar();
}
```

We can build this like so: `cl /MD use_bar.cpp trash8.lib`.

When we run it, we get about what you'd expect:

```
in bar
in foo
back in bar
```

That leaves only one more hurdle: getting Visual Studio to agree to do what you want. My immediate reaction is that the first thing to do is put the executable in one project, the DLL in a second project, and (if you're dealing with) the executable that uses the DLL in a third project, with a reference from the second to the first and from the third to the second.

Comment: This all presumes the OP has the original code from his .exe to modify.  If he does ... then there's no need to modify and rebuild the .exe .... nor is there any need for his "wrapper .dll" that "imports functionality" from the .exe.  Based on what the OP has said, it sounds like the "ideal" solution is to simply refactor the relevant code directly into a new .dll.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4: Not really. If his executable already uses the standard library in a DLL (which is pretty common) he doesn't need to rebuild it at all. It would only need rebuilding if it links the standard library statically (and might not even then, depending on what's in the functions he cares about using). A new DLL is undoubtedly the ideal, but a wrapper may easily save quite a lot of work.